# Determine if the series diverge or converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

So I was wondering what is the best TEST(divergent test, alternating series,power series,ratio test or root test) that we can use for the following series :

[image: The series]

Comment: $3^{2+n} 2^{1-3n}= 3^2\cdot 2\cdot (3/2^3)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify to $(\frac{3}{8})^n$ and it becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used the geometric series as noted in this website : 
[Pauls Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Series_Special.aspx)

Thank you guys anyway for such a fast response!